# UILabel's new text value not updating inside XCUI Test

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

So a few days ago I started using the 'new' XCUI Testing framework for tech evaluation purposes. I find the system quite shaky, as very often the tests start failing (typically, button presses using .tap() simply do not trigger the button action) and I need to restart Xcode and clear the DerivedData caches to get it working again. But this one thing I cannot get working at all - and it is about the simplest UI test use case available:

I have a UIButton and a UILabel. The UILabel initially has a text "initial text". The button's label is "SHOW MESSAGE". When the button is pressed, the label's text is changed to "new text". And obviously this works when running the app. ;)

However, when I run the following XCUI Test (app instance having been initialized and launch()ed in setup()):

```
    app.buttons["SHOW MESSAGE"].tap()
    XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["new text"].exists)
```

The test fails 100% of the time. When I print out (after the .tap() call) the static texts using `print(app.staticTexts.debugDescription)`, I can see my label there but with the original text of "initial text".

Is all of this XCUI stuff still just REALLY alpha stuff or what?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this was about needing to add a 1 second sleep() in the setUp() method to allow for the framework to initialize properly. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Set an accessibility identifier on the label and retrieve the text using XCUIElement.label.

```
XCTAssertEqual("new text", app.staticTexts["yourAccessibilityLabel"].label)
```

This should retrieve the latest text from the label.

The a new view hierarchy snapshot should be taken after you tap the button. There should be a debug log showing this when you try to find the label's new value. It should not mention using any cached snapshot.

Comment: Well, see, I've tried that also. I set the Accessibility Identifier of the label to `messageLabel` and tried that way but got the following error: `Assertion Failure: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("new text")") is not equal to ("Optional("initial text")") - `

Comment: It sounds like the view hierarchy hasn't refreshed for you to find the new value. Try using expectationForPredicate (or expectationWithDescription) and waitForExpectationsWithTimeout for a few seconds. This should force a view hierarchy refresh each time the check occurs.

Comment: Alternatively, the value may be being set in more than one place in your app code. Do you have a value set for the label in the storyboard or nib? This may override the value for XCTest when you change the value it in the event handler for the button being pressed. Set all label values programmatically and remove values from the storyboard/nib.

Comment: Good idea. However that didn't help; and looking at the simulator while the XCUI test runs, I can see the label text not changing during the test (easier to see it now with the `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout`), ie. the real problem seems to be that the .tap() does not trigger the button press.

Comment: Removing the default label string from the Storyboard didn't seem to do much either.. also it would not be sustainable solution as removing the values from the storyboard would not be viable design-wise.

Comment: Execute the test manually with the record function and see if there are any notable differences between your code and the generated code. Also check that the label's value has changed when you do it by hand.

Comment: What bothers me immensely is how sometimes the .tap() works, and sometimes it does not. If the tap() causes a visual action in the simulator, also the tests (at least some of them) work. And this behavior variance does not seem to be deterministic at all. By hammering CMD-U and/or occasionally removing the DerivedData caches, I might be lucky enough to make it work a few times -- then it starts failing again. Sigh. Yeah I have generated the test code steps with the record function. And yes the label changes properly when running the app and clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

try it with expectationForPredicate. Here the code:

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
let label = app.staticTexts["new text"]
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: label, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { error in
            if error != nil {
                assertionFailure("error")
            }
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: Tried that. The thing is that the label already has exists = true from the start of course. The actual problem here is that the `app.buttons["foobutton"].tap()` is not triggering the button's action most times, which I must consider a bug in the testing framework. There is no error from the tap(), it just does not do anything.